# Warning: Illegal string offset "Error al traer los resultados de una consulta"

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes, tengo el siguiente menú:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que al dar clic sobre cada categoría se mostraran solamente los productos de esa categoría, pero ne vez de mostrarme los productos me muestra esos errores, el código es el siguiente para la lógica:

```
    <?php

include 'conexion.php';

//Traer las categorias desde la base de datos

$consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM tcategoria");

$consulta->execute();

$categorias = $consulta->fetchAll();

if(!$conexion){
    die();
}

$idCat=isset($_GET['idCategoria']) ? (int) ($_GET['idCategoria']) : false;

if(!$idCat){
    header('Location: index.php');
}

$statement=$conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM tproducto WHERE idCategoria = :idCat');
$statement->execute(array(':idCat' => $idCat));

$categoria=$statement->fetch();

if(!$categoria){
    header('Location: index.php');
}

include 'views/listacategorias.view.php';

?>
```

Y el siguiente para la vista:

```
<div class="catprod">
    <nav class="categorias col-3 col-m-4">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($categorias as $categoria): ?>
        <li><a href="listacategorias.php?idCategoria=<?php echo $categoria['idCategoria']; ?>"><?php echo $categoria['Categoria']; ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</nav> 
<article class="imagenes col-9 col-m-8">
    <?php foreach($categoria as $cat):?>
    <div class="imagen1 col-4 col-m-6"> 
        <h2><?php echo $cat['Producto']; ?></h2>
        <a href="fotos.php?idProducto=<?php echo $foto['idProducto']; ?>">
            <img src="albumProductos/<?php echo $cat['Imagen'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $cat['Descripcion'] ?>">
        </a>
        <p><b>$: </b><?php echo $cat['Precio']; ?></p>
        <span class="icon-shopping-cart"></span><input type="submit" value="Comprar">
        </div>
    <?php endforeach;?> 
</article>
<div class="paginacion imagenes">
<?php if($pagina_actual > 1): ?>
    <a href="index.php?p=<?php echo $pagina_actual - 1; ?>" class="izquierda col-6 col-m-6"><span class="icon-arrow-left-alt1"></span> Página Anterior</a>
<?php endif ?>
<?php if($total_paginas != $pagina_actual): ?>
    <a href="index.php?p=<?php echo $pagina_actual + 1; ?>" class="derecha col-6 col-m-6">Página Siguiente <span class="icon-arrow-right-alt1"></span></a>
<?php endif ?>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: ¿En que línea y en cual archivo te manda el error?

Comment: el error te da por que estas escribiendo $cat["Producto"] php es caseSensitive colocalo todo en minuscula

Comment: Ejecuta por separado la consulta con que se llena $categoria y mira si "Producto" esta así con mayúscula y minúscula; asi mismo que el nombre del campo no tenga espacio; realiza las correcciones que apliquen según como se recibe.

Comment: ¿Dónde almacenas **realmente tu resultado**?. Pues según esto: `$categoria=$statement->fetch();` lo almacenas en una variable llamada `$categoria`, pero luego haces esto: `<?php foreach($categorias as $categoria): ?>` y luegoooo haces esto: `<?php foreach($categoria as $cat):?>` Lo cierto es que, **al final, después de tantas vueltas** en `$cat` no hay nada que tenga una clave  llamada `Producto`. Para depurar, yo trataría de aclararme en ese ir y venir de la variable `$categoria` y luego, cuando me decida por cuál es la buena haría un `print_r($categoriacorrecta);` para ver lo que hay en ella

Answer (score 6):

Este error es producido normalmente cuando intentas acceder a un string como si fuera un array.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php

$miArray = array('buenRollo'=>10, 'malRolo'=>0, 'diversion'=>10);
echo $miArray['diversion']; // muestra 10

$texto = "Esta es mi cadena de texto";
echo $texto['buenRollo']; // esto causa error: illegal string offset error...

?>
```

En tu ejemplo `$categoria=$statement->fetch();` devuelve una única fila, por lo que en la vista puedes prescindir del foreach para recorrerlo, pero si lo que quieres es retornar todas las categorias o filas y no solo una debes utilizar el método `fetchAll()` quedando así `$categoria=$statement->fetchAll();`

[Manual fetch()](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php)

[Manual fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: Gracias por sacarme de un problema, sin embargo si se accede al string como array el índice TIENE que ser un numero entero igual o mayor que cero

Comment: @Maxima Se puede acceder o modificar los caracteres de un string especificando el índice de base cero del carácter deseado empleando los corchetes de array o las llaves. Internamente, los string de PHP son arrays de bytes.