# Por que sale este error: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in line 13

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```html
<?php

 require("connect_db.php");
 
 
 
 

     foreach($_POST['idctg_dia'] as $index => $value) {
    // $value tendrá valor desde 1 (lunes) hasta 7 (domingo)
    $entrada = $_POST['hr_entrada'][$index];
    $salida = $_POST['hr_salida'][$index];
 $turno = $_POST['idctg_turno'][$index];
    // Aquí debes validar los datos antes de agregarlos a una consulta
 
 
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ctg_horario (idctg_dia, hr_entrada, hr_salida, idctg_turno) values ('$turno','$entrada','$salida', 'idctg_turno')")) {
  $turno = $_POST['idctg_turno'];
  $entrada = $_POST['hr_entrada'];
  $salida = $_POST['hr_salida'];
  
  if($stmt->execute()){  
    echo '<script>alert("Datos Ingresados Correctamente")</script> ';
        }
    }
}
?>

<html>

<head>

<form action="" method=post name="formulario">


<style>
div label
{
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
 
}


</style>


<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- FooTable Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="js/compiled/footable.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="js/demo-rows.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page">
   <div class="header">
    <a href="#menu"></a>
    Sistema Integral de Nómina
   </div>
   <h1 align="center">Gesti&oacute;n de Nómina</h1>
            <p align="center"><br /><input type="submit"  name="botonGuardar"class="bg-primary" value="Agregar"  /></p>
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Consulta de Horarios</strong>
   <a href="horario_edit.php" ><img src="images/file_get.png"  width="50" height="50" title="consultar" style="cursor:pointer"></a></p>

<title>Gesti&oacuten de Nómina</title>



<body>





<center><fieldset style="width:40%" "width:900px">




<legend >Registro de Nómina</legend>
<td>
 
 
    
<th><label>Selecciona el Turno:</label>
<table>

<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT idctg_turno, descripcion FROM ctg_turno";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[idctg_turno]\">$row[descripcion] </option>";   
   
}
?>

<select name="idctg_turno">
<option value="-">Selecciona el Turno</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select><br /><br />




               <tr>
          <th><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="idctg_dia[]"> Lunes</th>
               <th>Hora Entrada
                 <input type="time" name="hr_entrada[]">
               </th>
               <th>Hora Salida
                  <input type="time" name="hr_salida[]">
          </th></tr>
          <tr>
          <th><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="idctg_dia[]"> Martes</th>
               <th>Hora Entrada
                 <input type="time" name="hr_entrada[]">
               </th>
               <th>Hora Salida
                  <input type="time" name="hr_salida[]">
          </th></tr>
      
      
      
       
      
      
       

      
      
      
      
      
      
      
   
  
      
        
  
  
  
 
</td></table><center></fieldset><br></br>





</form>





   

    </html>
```

Comment: Revisa esta respuesta, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63679/warning-illegal-string-offset-error-al-traer-los-resultados-de-una-consulta/63704#63704   . `idctg_turno` no es un Array.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que tu problema no es un error, sino que esta marcado com Notice esto te indica posibles problemas de codigo que a simple vista no detectarias, accesos a variables no definidas, vacias, etc.. Me parece que tu problema viene derivado de que la primera vez que cargas la pagina no tienes $_POST y en el primer bucle estas haciendo accesos a dicha variable suponiendo que siempre tiene valores.

```
foreach($_POST['idctg_dia'] as $index => $value) {
```

En ningún momento verificas que $_POST['idctg_dia'] esté disponible