# Problema al mostrar un array obtenido con la función fetch_array()

Tags: php, php7

Tengo el siguiente **fichero** :

```
$usuario =$_SESSION['usuario'];


     $mensaje_controllers = new Mensaje();

     $result = $mensaje_controllers->verMensajesUsuario($usuario);

     var_dump($result);

     $array_datos = $result->fetch_array();

        foreach ($array_datos as $mensaje) {
            echo $mensaje['titulo'];
        }
```

- `$usuario` = obtengo su vlaor mediante la **sesion**. (**funciona**)
- `$mensaje_controllers->verMensajesUsuario($usuario);` = me devuelve
  los mensajes del usuario que le paso (**funciona**)
- `$array_datos` = convierto lso datos en array(**funciona**)

Pero a la hora de mostrarlo en mi página `ver_mis_mensajes.php`:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Inicio</title>
        <!-- IMPORT BOOTSRAP-CSS -->
        <?php include_once 'partials/bootstrap_css.php' ?>
            <!-- CSS 'FULL' -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos/full.css">
     </head>
     <body>


        <div class="container">
                    <?php include_once 'partials/menu.php'; ?>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                <!-- CUERPO -->
                    <?php include_once "procesos/ver_mis_mensajes.php" ?>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>



        <!-- IMPORT BOOTSRAP JQUERY -->
        <?php include_once 'partials/bootstrap_jquery.php' ?>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Me dice `Warning: Illegal string offset 'titulo'` a la hora de hacer el mostrarlo.

Comment: Puedes encontrar la solución a tu problema en el siguiente enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63679/warning-illegal-string-offset-error-al-traer-los-resultados-de-una-consulta

Comment: Gracias por la informacion , era por eso, pero una cosa muy curiosa es que cuando **displayeo** los valores no me salen todos (la consulta esta bien hecha) y no me los trae en **orden** algo que me ha sorprendido, a lo mejor me trae `[mensaje.id,mensaje.id,mensaje.titulo,mensaje.titulo]` asi **mezclando** los valores. SIn **ningun tipo de orden** . Y esta forma no puedo tratar con ellos

Answer (score 1):

Este error es producido normalmente cuando intentas acceder a un string como si fuera un array.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php

$miArray = array('buenRollo'=>10, 'malRolo'=>0, 'diversion'=>10);
echo $miArray['diversion']; // muestra 10

$texto = "Esta es mi cadena de texto";
echo $texto['buenRollo']; // esto causa error: illegal string offset error...

?>
```