# Warning: Illegal string offset

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy con mi hermana trabajando en un sitio para administrar usuarios y tengo este codigo que permite eliminar al usuario. Si el usuario esta inscripto a más de una escuela, se le elimina la contraseña (de la tabla de usuarioesc) y los cursos a que esta inscripto (tabla de cursantes). Pero si el usuario esta inscripto a 1 sola escuela, se lo elimina completamente (tabla de usuarios, usuarioesc y cursantes). Hasta ahora tenemos escrito esto:

```
function eliminarUsuario()
{
    $id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'];
    $id_escuela = isset ($_POST['id_escuela']);
    
    $link = conectar();
    $buscaRepetidos = "SELECT COUNT(id_usuario) AS cuenta
                        FROM usuarioesc 
                        WHERE id_usuario= '".$id_usuario."' GROUP BY id_usuario";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($link, $buscaRepetidos);

    if ( $buscaRepetidos["cuenta"] > 1 ) {
//Si esta en más de 1 escuela se elimina de las siguietes tablas//
        "DELETE FROM usuarioesc WHERE id_usuario= '".$id_usuario."' AND id_escuela='".$id_escuela."'";

        "DELETE cu FROM cursantes AS cu INNER JOIN cursada AS cs ON cu.id_cursada = cs.id_cursada WHERE cs.id_escuela = '".$id_escuela."' AND cu.id_usuario = '".$id_usuario."'";

    } else {
        
    if ( $buscaRepetidos["cuenta"] = 1 ) {
//Si es igual a 1 se elimina de esta tabla//
        "DELETE FROM usuarioesc WHERE id_usuario= '".$id_usuario."' AND id_escuela='".$id_escuela."'";
    
        }
        
    }

    }
```

Pero salta el siguiente error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'cuenta' in
> C:...\funciones\usuarios.php on line 83
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'cuenta' in
> C:...\funciones\usuarios.php on line 93

Línea 83 es `if ( $buscaRepetidos["cuenta"] > 1 ) {`

Línea 93 es `"DELETE FROM usuarioesc WHERE id_usuario= '".$id_usuario."' AND id_escuela='".$id_escuela."'";`

Lei diferentes posts con el mismo error pero no entiendo como lo solucionan. Perdon por las molestias, recien empiezo con php.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 83?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Warning: Illegal string offset "Error al traer los resultados de una consulta"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63679/warning-illegal-string-offset-error-al-traer-los-resultados-de-una-consulta)

Comment: Tu consulta muestra que estás obteniendo N filas, pero luego directo en el `if` tratas de acceder a una clave, si tu consulta devuelve un array entonces como dice el enlace asociado debes hacer un ciclo e iterar los valores

Comment: @BetaM Ahi agrege las lineas en la pregunta.

Comment: la solución esta en el enlace que te he provisto

Comment: Ahi lo lei. Me cuesta entenderlo pero creo que lo que entendi es que tengo que agregar un fetchAll. Seria algo asi? `if ( $buscaRepetidos->fetchAll()["cuenta"] > 1 ) {`  pero ahora dice `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll(` . Entonces que tendria que ver en este posteo? Perdon Beta si te molesto, intento de entenderlo pero es bastante complejo.

Comment: Intente con otros equivalentes y sigue teniendo errores. Es una lastima, no se que se tiene que poner o escribir o cual es el error.

Comment: No estás aplicando ningún método fetch para obtener el resultado de la consulta. Es un error básico, si lees lo que explica el Manual de PHP podrás resolver este error sin mayor dificultad.

Comment: Lei el manual (y otras partes similares) y no entenidi. Si me podrias explicar o decir donde esta el error te lo ree agradeceria. La verdad es que no tengo idea por que no anda el codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Causa del error

El error *`Illegal string offset`* ocurre porque estás tratando una cadena como si fuese un array.

Aquí por ejemplo:

```
if ( $buscaRepetidos["cuenta"] > 1 ) {
```

Realmente, `$buscaRepetidos` es una cadena en la que escribiste tu instrucción SQL:

```
$buscaRepetidos = "SELECT COUNT(id_usuario) AS cuenta
                    FROM usuarioesc 
                    WHERE id_usuario= '".$id_usuario."' GROUP BY id_usuario";
```

No es un array con una llave llamada `cuenta`, para poder hacer esto: `$buscaRepetidos["cuenta"]`

### Solución

Tu error ocurre debido a una compresión errónea sobre el funcionamiento de la API mysqli, que estás usando para consultar a la base de datos.

Cuando ejecutas `mysqli_query()`, si todo va bien, obtendrás **un recurso** que apunta a los datos, (ojo, que puse **un recurso** en negritas), porque `mysqli_query()` no te devuelve los datos, sino algo así como un puntero hacia ellos, y luego tienes que extraer los datos con alguno de los métodos/funciones destinados para ello, que son varios, y dependendiendo de cómo quieres organizar la salida de los datos, usarás alguno de esos métodos, que son los métodos `fetch_`.

Entendido eso, no tendrás mayores complicaciones con la API en cuanto a lectura de datos. Ahora lo aplicamos en tu código:

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($link, $buscaRepetidos);
/*
   Aplicamos uno de los métodos fetch, que es mysqli_fetch_assoc
   que te devuelve los datos como array asociativo
   Esa parece ser tu intención en el código
   Además, por el tipo de consulta parece que esperas una sola fila
   Si se esperasen varias filas, debes recorrer el puntero con los datos
   dentro de un bucle para irlos sacando, en el Manual de PHP
   hay ejemplos sobre esto (ver enlace al final),
   aquí no se necesita bucle
 */
$mData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

/*
   $mData sí es un array con los datos 
   y podrás hacer la comparación adecuadamente
*/

if ( $mData["cuenta"] > 1 ) {
    # Resto del código

/*
   Ojo, esta comparación está mal en tu código
   debes usar al menos dos signos ==, 
   si usas uno solo no comparas nada, asignas el valor
*/
if ( $mData["cuenta"] == 1 ) {
```

Con eso el código debería funcionar, salvo que haya otros errores que deberás corregir adecuadamente.

### Recomendaciones

1. Tu código es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Un usuario mal intencionado podría causar estragos en tu sistema mediante este código.
2. Considera escribir un código estricto, que verifique el estado de las variables y controle los errores que pudieran ocurrir (no hay conexión, consulta incorrecta, etc).

### Enlaces

1. Cómo funciona [mysqli_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)
2. El método o función [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) que hemos utilizado aquí para leer los datos.

Comment: Ahora entiendo! Muchas gracias @Cedano por la explicación y paciencia. Lo voy a tener en cuenta.