# Illegal Offset String en el update de un CRUD, PHP

Tags: php, base-de-datos, crud

[image: Código problemático]

Buenas tardes gente, estoy haciendo un ABM con la plantilla MVC y cuando estoy por la parte del Update, me tira el siguiente error en la línea de $datos['actualizarNombre']

**Warning: Illegal string offset 'actualizarNombre' in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDO-MYSQL\modelos\formularios-modelo.php on line 64**

El código en cuestión:

//static public function mdlActualizarRegistro($tabla, $datos)
{

```
    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare( //linea 4 + prepare
        "UPDATE $tabla SET nombre=:nombre, email=:email, password=:password WHERE id=:id"
    );

    $stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $datos['actualizarNombre'], PDO::PARAM_STR); //bindParam linkea un parametro a una variable predeterminada
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $datos['actualizarEmail'], PDO::PARAM_STR); //a :email, le voy a linkear lo que ponga en el input "actualizarEmail" de la pestaña editar.
    $stmt->bindParam(":password", $datos['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR); //$datos['loquesea'] viene de formularios-controlador, en el momento en que yo declaré al array $datos 
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $datos['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT); //$datos['loquesea'] viene de formularios-controlador, en el momento en que yo declaré al array $datos 

    if ($stmt->execute()) { //si $stmt se ejecuta y está todo correcto, devuelve "ok"

        return "ok"; //devuelve "ok". Y este "ok" se linkea con paginas/registro.php, para poner el alert de que la operación es correcta.
    } else {
        print_r(Conexion::conectar()->errorInfo());
        exit;
        $stmt->null;
    }
   //recolección de datos
    $datos = array(
        "id" => $_POST['idUsuario'],
        "nombre" => $_POST['actualizarNombre'],
        "email" => $_POST['actualizarEmail'],
        "password" => $password,
    );
    
}
```

EDIT: Agregué el array $datos.

EDIT: Me apareció un error nuevo

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Only variables can be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDO-MYSQL\modelos\formularios-modelo.php:66 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PDO-MYSQL\vistas\paginas\editar.php(39): ModeloFormularios::mdlActualizarRegistro('id', '1') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\PDO-MYSQL\vistas\plantilla.php(92): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\PDO-MYSQL\controladores\plantilla-controlador.php(7): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\PDO-MYSQL\index.php(12): ControladorPlantilla->ctrTraerPlantilla() #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDO-MYSQL\modelos\formularios-modelo.php on line 66**
La linea 66 es la de actualizarNombre también

Comment: ahí lo agregué, aunque no mediante var_dump porque no lograba imprimirlo en pantalla.

Comment: el array $datos está declarado en un archivo de la carpeta controladores, y el error me lo está dando en un archivo de la carpeta modelos. El problema de hacer las cosas así, es que no entiendo una mierda y solo le copio al flaco, pero en cuanto aparece un error estoy cagado.

Mi plan era copiar el ejercicio, y después hacerlo solo entendiendo por donde va cada cosa, pero la verdad que no lo estoy pudiendo terminar.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Warning: Illegal string offset "Error al traer los resultados de una consulta"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63679/warning-illegal-string-offset-error-al-traer-los-resultados-de-una-consulta)

Comment: Vi ese post, pero yo si estoy queriendo acceder a un array, eso es lo que no termino de entender.

Comment: Por lo que veo estás queriendo usar la llave "actualizarNombre" que usaste en $_POST pero no existe en $datos.

Comment: Me acaba de sumar un error nuevo... No se que toqué jajaja

Comment: Pero me parece raro que no funcione, porque en la sección de registrar usuarios, dentro del modelo también, si me funciona.
    static public function mdlRegistro($tabla, $datos)
    {
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare( //linea 4 + prepare
            "INSERT INTO $tabla (nombre, email, password) VALUES (:nombre, :email, :password)"
        );

$stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $datos['nombre'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
   if ($stmt->execute()) { 
return true; 
     } else {
        print_r(Conexion::conectar()->errorInfo());
       exit;
    $stmt->null

Comment: El nuevo error está en la línea `66` del archivo `formularios-modelo.php`, ¿qué hay en esa línea? Estás pasando un valor hardcoded por referencia y no puedes hacer eso, tienes que declarar una variable si quieres pasar por referencia.

Answer (score 0):

El error *`Only variables can be passed by reference`* ocurre porque, [como dice el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php) (las negritas son mías) `bindParam()`:

> Vincula una variable de PHP a un parámetro de sustitución con nombre o
> de signo de interrogación correspondiente de la sentencia SQL que fue
> usada para preparar la sentencia. A diferencia de
> `PDOStatement::bindValue()`, **la variable es vinculada como una
> referencia** y solamente será evaluada en el momento en el que se
> llame a `PDOStatement::execute()`.

Significa que con `bindParam()` **sólo puedes usar variables directas u obtenidas por referencia**, no resultados de llamadas a métodos o resultados de arrays, a no ser que indiques en la lectura que el valor se obtendrá por referencia ([ver este ejemplo al respecto](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php#98145)).

Para este caso, puedes cambiar `bindParam()` por `bindValue()`, el cual no vincula por referencia, sino por valor.

```
$stmt->bindValue(":nombre", $datos['actualizarNombre'], PDO::PARAM_STR); //bindParam linkea un parametro a una variable predeterminada
$stmt->bindValue(":email", $datos['actualizarEmail'], PDO::PARAM_STR); //a :email, le voy a linkear lo que ponga en el input "actualizarEmail" de la pestaña editar.
$stmt->bindValue(":password", $datos['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR); //$datos['loquesea'] viene de formularios-controlador, en el momento en que yo declaré al array $datos 
$stmt->bindValue(":id", $datos['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT); //$datos['loquesea'] viene de formularios-controlador, en el momento en que yo declaré al array $datos
```